# Laravel Email Queue not sending email

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, swiftmailer

I am trying to send the email( using queue). I am experiencing this strange behavior with the Laravel queue, it sends email perfectly in sync but does not send an email when send using a queue. And If I remove the queue it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Laravel `queue` process work under the `queue runner`, check your runner !

It might help https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both queue:work and queue:listen, but the user is not getting email.

Comment: Which driver you are using to manage queue ?

Comment: I tried with the database and Redis.

Comment: The job storing in your DB ? Did you migrated the jobs table ?

Comment: Yes, I have a jobs table.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, try this

.env file setup MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail.

config/mail.php file 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t' replace -bs with -t.